# KQL - Remove Characters from String

Tags: kql

just starting out with KQL, I currently have a string which is set to: "server1-Incremantal")
I am looking to remove the front '"' and trailing '")' . So effectively just reads "server1-Incremantal" (without the quotes) any help to get this done will greatly appreciated!!

I am looking to for the string to read "server1-Incremantal" (without the quotes) any help to get this done will greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [`parse` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseoperator).

other functions you may find helpful are:

- [`trim_end()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/trimendfunction)
- [`trim_start()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/trimstartfunction)
- [`trim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/trimfunction)
- [`substring()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/substringfunction)

for example:

```
print input = '"server1-Incremantal")'
| parse input with '"' output '")'
```

| input | output |
| --- | --- |
| "server1-Incremantal") | server1-Incremantal |